How can I place a checkbox next to Bootstrap tab text and align all in the tab?
Could someone help me align the text and checkbox so they are both inside the Tabs here please, preferably without CSS or using inline CSS.
Ive tried a few diffent approaches, but bootstrap isn't my strong suit, im using a CRUD framework that handles the bootstrap side of things, but I need to do somthing like this so the end user can select tabs to export.
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  
    <!-- Tab 1 with Checkbox -->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
        <span class="d-flex align-items-center">
          Badger
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkTab1">
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    
    <!-- Tab 2 with Checkbox -->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
        <span class="d-flex align-items-center">
          Cat
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkTab2">
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    
    <!-- Tab 2 with Checkbox -->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
        <span class="d-flex align-items-center">
          Foo
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkTab3">
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    
    <!-- Tab 2 with Checkbox -->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
        <span class="d-flex align-items-center">
          Bar
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkTab4">
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

Fiddle here

in your case can use d-flex and align-items-center classes or use custom css, bootstrap tab borders and padding interfere with the checkbox placement
<div class="container">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
    <span>Badger</span>
    <input class="form-check-input ms-auto" type="checkbox" id="checkTab1">
  </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
    <span>Cat</span>
    <input class="form-check-input ms-auto" type="checkbox" id="checkTab2">
  </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
    <span>Foo</span>
    <input class="form-check-input ms-auto" type="checkbox" id="checkTab3">
  </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
    <span>Bar</span>
    <input class="form-check-input ms-auto" type="checkbox" id="checkTab4">
  </a>
</li>


Thanks @Marwen unfortunately that is somthing I had tried and does not work, your code here: link As you can see the check box is still intersected by the border of the tab.

That still doesnt work. New Fiddle
